# How do you export a Map data type column on DynamoDB to S3 with JSON data type using HiveQL on EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

There are records that map data type on DynamoDB, I want to export these records to S3 with JSON data format using HiveQL on EMR.
How do you do this one? Is it possible?

I read the following documentaion, but that I wanted information was nothing.

- DynamoDB DataFormat Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataFormat.html
- Hive Command Examples for Exporting... Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html

I tried the following steps:

1. Create a table on DynamoDB

   ```
   TableName: DynamoDBTable1
   HashKey: user_id
   ```
2. Insert two records to DynamoDB

   ```
   # record1
   user_id: "0001"
   json: {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}

   # record2
   user_id: "0001"
   json: {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
   ```
3. Create a table on EMR from DynamoDB

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (user_id string, json map<string, string>)
   STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
   TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "DynamoDBTable", 
   "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "user_id:user_id,json:json");
   ```
4. Export records to S3

   ```
   INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://some-bucket/exports/' select json from test where user_id = '0001';
   ```
5. Confirm the S3 bucket, but the exported data is not JSON format...

   ```
   # Expected
   [
     {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"},
     {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
   ]

   # Actual
   key1^C{"s":"value1"}^Bkey2^C{"s":"value2"}
   key1^C{"s":"value1"}^Bkey2^C{"s":"value2"}
   ```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? or find a work around?

Comment: still no workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The following DynamoDB data types are not supported by the DynamoDBStorageHandler class, so they cannot be used with dynamodb.column.mapping:

Map,
List,
Boolean,
Null